# Accessing a development LAMP server as if it were the live server by faking the URL

Tags: url, webserver, lamp, configuration, development

At the moment I have my test server set-up like so `http://localhost/~callum` but I want to set-up a fake url so I can link javascripts and CSS files from my PHP files. Hope this makes sense any help is much a appreciated.
I should also say I am using a public_html folder and not var/www.

EDIT: What I mean by fake url is that I want to turn my url from `http://localhost/~callum` to something like this `http://callumstestwebsite.com/` without owning the domain so that I can continue to develop on my new laptop, I used to use windows 7 so I am getting used to ubuntu.

Comment: What do you think a 'fake' URL would look like?

Comment: Presumably you want to setup a URL like `http://example.com` in local DNS?

Comment: What I mean by 'fake_url' is that I want to turn my domain to something like www.callumstestwebsite.com/ instead of localhost/~callum so that I can link my css and JavaScript files. Sorry for not posting sooner I was at school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access a local resource as if it were the main site you need to do two things:

1. Edit your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) such that your computer thinks that your domain name is served by localhost.  Your hosts file should contain a line with 127.0.0.1 in it and your host name would need to be added to that line, something like: `127.0.0.1 localhost callumstestwebsite.com`  Use the command line `sudo editor /etc/hosts` to edit this file.
2. Configure your webserver to serve the website when a request is made for that host name.  It appears that you are currently serving the site only when there is a path of `/~callum` but you would need to configure the webserver differently.  Generally this would entail adding a [virtualhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) directive something like (for apache server in `httpd.conf`):

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/callum/public_html
    ServerName callumstestwebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In my Debian based distribution I would create a file called `/etc/apache2/sites-available/callumstestwebsite` with that contents (and any other needed configuration), then enable the site with the command: `sudo a2ensite callumstestwebsite`, then restart my webserver with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant. Sorry for those who posted earlier I was still half a sleep before I went to school.

Comment: if possible could you give me the command lines?

Comment: I've added several command lines that I would use for my distribution (Ubuntu, debian based).  Different distributions do apache configuration differently, so your milage may vary.